# Phantomjs only renders blank pictures from local html files

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

the task is quite simple, I guess. I would like to produce screenshots (png - files) from local html files.

My 'proof of concept' looks like this...
The files are located on a windows 10 machine in a local folder: c:\temp\

This would be a very basic html file - just to make sure that no sophisticated stuff is disturbing (file called: a.html):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- otherwise format might be broken when opening from local source -->
        <title>Savills Charts</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>HalloBallo</h1>
<p>My baby baby, Balla Balla!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The script which calls phantomjs was taken from here: http://www.cameronjtinker.com/post/2011/09/26/Take-Screenshot-of-all-HTML-documents-in-a-folder-using-PhantomJS.aspx
During my work I thought my own script was the problem but it doesn't look like it is.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open("file:///c:/temp/a.html", function() {   
    page.render('C:/temp/screenshot.png');  
  phantom.exit();
});
```

phantomjs is producing only black .png files. 
If I switch the source from something local to something on the web

page.open("file:///c:/temp/a.html"

to

page.open("http://spon.de"

then everything works fine....
I'm lost... 
What can I do?

KR, 
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someday someone stumbles as I did.
Therefore I want to clearify. The problem was, that (in contrast to a web browser) phantomjs does not set any colors by default. So in the website given (see example code) phantomjs simply renders black writing on black background.

If you give the body a backgroundcolor then you will see the black font.

So - it's solved.

Martin